# How to place text on seperate line and make banner full width of the page

Tags: html, css

I have got two question:

1. How do i make the banner the full width of the page has i have set the width to 100% and I have search the internet and it also tells me to set the width to 100%, which I have done.
2. How do I move some text to the second line as i have tried 
    and  and I have also searched the internet regarding this issue and attempted all methods, but nothing seems to be working as i want "JOIN SOCIAL CLUB" on a new line just below "SIGN IN".

Again I have tried setting the width to 100% and it has worked to an extent, but I am left with a white space on the right.

I have tried 
 and  and I have also searched the internet regarding this issue and attempted all methods, but nothing seems to be working for question 2.

I have i done anything wrong or do i need to add anything?

The code down below is for both Q1 & 2

My HTML Code:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/solid.css">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="modal-dialog text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-9 main-section">
            <div class="col-12 logo">
                <img src="img/logo.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="col-12 banner">
    <img class="banner-image" src="img/1.jpg">
</div>
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Newswire</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Social Club</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Warehouse</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-search"></i></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="global">
  <a href="#">SIGN IN</a> <p>Or</p> <a href="#">JOHN SOCIAL CLUB</a>
</div>
```

My CSS Code is:

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 130px;
}
.logo img {
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-left: 100px
}
.logo {
    margin-top: -60px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.banner {
    width: 150%;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -250px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.banner > .banner-image {
    width: 150%;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -250px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
#nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float:left;
    list-style: none;
}
#nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: block;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
.box{
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}
.fa-search {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
.global {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #000;
  font-family: DINNext-Med,sans-serif;
  color: #777;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  min-width: 100px;
  margin-top: -220px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.global p {
  display: inline-block
  color: #777;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px
}
.global a {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OwEP.jpg (Question 1)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VufG3.jpg (Question 2)

Any help appreciated and thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! There are a lot of different issues on the code you provided. Most elements seem to be off the top of the screen (probably because of  `margin-top` with negative values). Will make for a clearer question if you can isolate to a single verifiable issue. I can extract the bit related to Question 2 and show you how to get those links on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

Banner:

```
<div class="container-fluid test">
  <div class="col h-100">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test {
  background-image: url(bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**EDIT:** **Question 2:**

HTML

```
<div class="global text-left">
  <a href="#">SIGN IN</a> <p>Or</p>
  <a href="#" class="d-block">JOHN SOCIAL CLUB</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
remove flex:wrap; from global 
fix display: inline-block in .global p
add display: inline-block in global a
```

Comment: There is no change :/

Comment: For both? Testing on my end and both worked. Did you replace the image url in the `.test` css?

Comment: For the banner try: `<div class="jumbotron-fluid test h-100"></div>` with the css that i provided for `.test`. That should fix all whitespace issues.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one you need to make sure that all the parent elements also sprawl the entire width.

As for the second question you need to change the display property to block, becasue the a tag is set to inline by default

```
a{
   display: block
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Global css class like this.

```css
.global {
    background: #000;
    font-family: DINNext-Med,sans-serif;
    color: #777;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    min-width: 100px;
    margin-top: -220px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: It has put "OR on a separate line and JOIN SOCIAL CLUB on a separate line and their is a big gap between OR and join social club :/

Answer (score 0):

If I isolate just this bit of HTML, with no CSS it seems to do what you want, even though you may have not intended it this way. The `<p>Or</p>` element is occupying the entire width which makes the links before and after appear on their own lines. This is due to the `p` element having block display property by default.

```html
<div class="global">
  <a href="#">SIGN IN</a> <p>Or</p> <a href="#">JOHN SOCIAL CLUB</a>
</div>
```

The `a` tags are displaying inline by default which is what allows them to flow in-line with text. To make them take up the whole width you can change their display property with CSS. Here I am taking away the `p` tag to demonstrate the `a` tag's new layout characteristic:

```css
.global a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="global">
  <a href="#">SIGN IN</a> Or <a href="#">JOHN SOCIAL CLUB</a>
</div>
```

I recommend you read up on the `display` property of CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

For other layout issues you are having, read up a bit about the box model of CSS, which it is always a good idea to work with instead of fight against (negative margins as you are using them is an example of fighting against the normal flow of boxes in my opinion). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model